# using a thunk to factor time out of async code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, redux-thunk

[Kyle Simpson](https://github.com/getify) has an amazing [class](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/rethinking-asynchronous-programming/table-of-contents) on pluralsight.

In one of the modules, he goes through a snippet of code that can be safely called asynchronously, and be certain that the results are going to be shown to the user in the same sequence with which the code was executed.

The function in its glory:

```
    function getFile(file) {
    var text, fn;

    fakeAjax(file, function(response){
        if (fn) fn(response);
        else text = response;
    });

    return function(cb) {
        if (text) cb(text);
        else fn = cb;
    }
 }
```

We can call it like so:

[image]

I'm having a tough time understanding the getFile function:

1. where is cb defined? how does it get called, i.e. `cb(text)` if it's not defined anywhere?
2. when we call getFile, how does the `response` get a value at all?

Answer (score 3):

`getFile` returns an anonymous function:

```
return function(cb) {
    if (text) cb(text);
    else fn = cb;
}
```

so `var th1 = getFile("file")` ends up assigning that anonymous function to the value of `th1`, so `th1` can now be called with an argument - which becomes `cb`.  So when later, we call `th1` with:

```
th1(function(text1) {
...
```

we are passing in a *second* anonymous function (with argument text1) which is assigned to `cb` (shorthand for 'callback').

The reason it works is that when the ajax is complete, it does one of two things:

- if `fn` is defined, calls `fn` with the response
- if not, it stores the response

Conversely, when the returned anonymous function is called, it does one of two things:

- if `text` is defined (i.e. a result is already received) then it calls the callback with the response
- if not, it assigns the callback (`cb`) to `fn`

This way, whichever happens first - ajax complete, or thunk called, the state is preserved, and then whichever happens second, the outcome is executed.

In this way, the 'thunks' can be chained to ensure that while the ajax functions happen in parallel the output methods are only called in the sequence in which the `fn` values are assigned.

I think part of the confusion is unclear variable naming, and the use of liberal anonymous functions with out giving them an intention revealing name.  The following should be functionally equivalent with clearer naming (I think):

```
function getFile(file) {
    var _response, _callback;

    fakeAjax(file, function(response){
        if (_callback) _callback(response);
        else _response = response;
    });

    var onComplete = function(callback) {
        if (_response) callback(_response);
        else _callback = callback;
    }

    return onComplete;
}
```

then:

```
var onFile1Complete = getFile("file1");
var onFile2Complete = getFile("file2");
var onFile3Complete = getFile("file3");

var file3Completed = function(file3Response) {
    output("file3Response");
    output("Complete!");
}

var file2Completed = function(file2Response) {
    output(file2Response);
    onfile3Complete(file3Completed)
}

var file1Completed = function(file1Response) {
    output(file1Response);
    onFile2Complete(file2Completed);
}

onFile1Complete(file1Completed);
```